# Jest mocking is not working for a specific file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am in a weird state for a file (I use Jest/React/Flux/Webpack)... here is the test file.

```
jest.unmock('../dashboard');

import CommonUtils from "../utils/CommonUtils";

describe('Dashboard Page', () => {
    it('creates', () => {
        ...
    });
});
```

When I run the test, an error is thrown:

```
● Runtime Error
  - TypeError: (0 , _shouldUpdate2.default) is not a function
        ...
        at Object.<anonymous> (src\main\js\components\App.js:3:38)
        at Object.<anonymous> (src\main\js\utils\CommonUtils.js:4:38)
        at Object.<anonymous> (src\test\js\dashboard-test.js:3:46)
```

Here, `CommonUtils` is clearly not mocked. In my other files, the auto mock is working just fine.

If I add at the beginning of the test file:

```
jest.mock('../utils/CommonUtils');
```

Same previous error... However, if I add this:

```
jest.mock('../utils/CommonUtils', () => {
    return {someFunc: jest.fn()};
});
```

`CommonUtils` is now mocked, but I cannot compare the mock object from `someFunc`, since it is always recreated... and I cannot create the variable outside

```
var a = {someFunc: jest.fn()};
jest.mock('../utils/CommonUtils', () => {
    return a;
});
```

Jest doesn't allow it!

Comment: are you trying to test `someFunc` to be called with something? can you show your code

Comment: Finally I have disabled the automock, it was too tricky. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have updated Jest and it disabled the auto mock. This is not conclusive, but no more reproducible.